# how can i encrypt dll files for hide?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, dll, .net-assembly

For security, I want to do the encrypt and decrypt methods using the methods in another dll file. But since this dll file will work on the user side, I don't want it to see the algorithm and unique key value I used for encrypt.
How can I prevent it from inspecting the codes when it goes to definition?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLdNd.png)

Comment: Forget about it. The only secure thing you can do here is to not offer to call such methods. So, that means you would have to decrypt while not doing the decryption in the user program's process. You might now think about having your methods in some secured privileged process with some inter-process communication between this and the user program's process. But then again, who owns the computer this is running on? Think about it what it means if the user themselves is controlling their own computer.

Comment: You basically have only option if you don't want to expose your decryption information: You have to run the decryption on a system you control, and only you. So, pretty much something like a web service perhaps (which aligns with the `asp.net` tag you have included in your question).